# Jquery Sortable and Draggable between parent and child frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to implement jQuery Draggable|Droppable|Sortable between a parent and child frame.
I have a this prototype but there is some weird behavior happening

```
win = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow;

element = win.document.getElementById('sortable');
$(element).sortable();
console.log(element);
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: $(element),
     iframefix: true,
    helper: function() {return $("<div/>").css('background-color','red');}
});
```

The iframe page also contains

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vxAzs/5/

It works fine when I try to drop the element on the iframe but when I try to sort the elements on the iframe the element sticks to the click event of both pages I think (so it doesn't get dropped until I click on both parent and iframes). I think it is something to do with the .sortable() call in both parent and iframe but if I remove that the droppable stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, here is how I am doing this one..
To create Drag on an element from parent frame and drop it in a sortable list in the iframe,
I created draggable on the element of parent frame from inside the iframe

```
win = document.getElementById('<identifier for Iframe>').contentWindow;
win.jQuery(dragelement,parent.document).draggable({
connectToSortable : $("#sortable")
)}
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: it is giving me this error .. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'jQuery' . Please help me how you solved this.

Comment: jquery is added on both side. I am using jquery 1.8.

Comment: here is fiddle link. This is giving error http://jsfiddle.net/vaibhav1407/VteaR/1/

Comment: Thanks, according your code, I wrote a worked demo(fix some error), may helps other people: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vxAzs/137/show/ (must test in preview page, otherwise, js SecurityError will show)

Answer (score 0):

comment this line in your code,

```
//$(element).sortable({iframefix:true});
```

here is the fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qHWN2/)

Comment: if I do that then the element doesn't get connected with the sortable list

Answer (score 0):

iframeFix is case sensitive:
Change

```
iframefix: true,
```

to

```
iframeFix: true,
```