# jQuery sortable / draggable iframe item sticks to cursor

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am working on a editor which uses an iframe. In that iframe i have a jQuery sortable list and outside the iframe i have draggable objects that i want to drag inside the iframe. All this is well and done.

The problem is that when i sort the list inside the iframe and i move the cursor outside the iframe, the item is still stuck on the cursor and out of the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/vxAzs/5/
The fiddler is from: [Jquery Sortable and Draggable between parent and child frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928210/jquery-sortable-and-draggable-between-parent-and-child-frame)

Page code:

```
win = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow; 
element = win.document.getElementById('sortable');
$(element).sortable({iframefix:true});
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: $(element),
  iframefix: true
});
```

Iframe code:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

The weird thing is that even when you sort the list in the iframe, all events (start, stop, deactivate) are called, but when you move your cursor outside the iframe, the "parent" sort function calls the start event again! somehow they are linked and i can't prevent it...

Tried preventing a parent call of the same event (event.stopPropagation();) and even making a function in the parent to disable the sortable when sorting in the iframe, but non had any effect...

Didn't find much on Google or stack about this.

Thanks in advance for helping!