# AngularJS jQuery ui-sortable inside an iframe cannot connectWith other sortable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, iframe, angular-ui

Problem:

I'm trying to make the jquery sortable ([angular-ui ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)) work inside an iFrame and it doesn't seem to behave the way it should be.

Scenario.

1. When trying to click and drag elements inside the iframe you should move the mouse outside the iframe then hover it back to the iframe to activate. I'm assuming that when you click inside the sortable inside the iFrame it doesn't fire unless you move your mouse on the parent document. I tried logging the event on my local test and it's the best guess I have.

Question:

1. Obviously working with iFrame is a pain but I need to use iFrame to avoid conflicts inside the dragged elements inside the iFrame.
2. Is there another alternative to this approach, I've been trying to work on this for days now.

Thanks in advance, every help is very much appreciated.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IQ0qFu606mVlg9DFCFei?p=preview

See the Non-iFrame example for the expected behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Sortable and Draggable between parent and child frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928210/jquery-sortable-and-draggable-between-parent-and-child-frame)