# Make custom HTML elements droppable in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I like to have a list which elements can be dropped in a list in an iframe similar to [this example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable). I found a working solution via [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928210/jquery-sortable-and-draggable-between-parent-and-child-frame) but in my case I need other elements than `<li>`'s.

Here's my setup:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>To drop 1</li>
        <li>To drop 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
```

and the iframe content:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
```

This works as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8cx4pe2y/).

It even works when changing the `<ul>` and `<li>`'s to `<div>` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8cx4pe2y/1/) and [iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/dd9wf04w/2/)).

When I use custom tags [it's working](http://jsfiddle.net/8cx4pe2y/2/) with `<foo>` and `<bar>` tags but what I really need is to get it working with `<modules>` and `<module>` tags.

```
<foo id="sortable">  //WORKS!!
    <bar>Element</bar>
    <bar>Element</bar>
    <bar>Element</bar>
</foo>

<modules id="sortable"> //DOESN'T WORK!!
    <module>Element</module>
    <module>Element</module>
    <module>Element</module>
</modules>
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cx4pe2y/3/) and the [iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/dd9wf04w/4/) of what I actually need to work.

So basically the **draggable** and **sortable** method is not working with my custom html tags. What's so different between `<foo>`, `<bar>` and `<modules>`, `<module>`?

**UPDATE**

It seems this is an issue on webkit browsers only since it's working fine on FF - wasn't able to test on a Windows machine yet.

When dragging the element it will create a "helper" which gets some inline style:

```
position:absolute;left:XXXpx;right:XXXpx;width:XXXpx;heightXXXpx;z-index:1000
```

while on webkits it only get `position`, `left` and `right`:

```
position:absolute;left:XXXpx;right:XXXpx;
```

Comment: It is working for me on `https://jsfiddle.net/8cx4pe2y/3/`, considering that the `iframe` has `src=/dd9wf04w/4/show/`

Comment: which browser/os? Can you get a "To drop" element into the list of "Element"s?

Comment: not working here: Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit), OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: Chrome on Windows doesn't work. Edge on Windows 10 actually sort of works, but is clunky. IE11 on Windows works inconsistently, and is clunky. What you are doing is really not a good idea with iframes. I'm sure there are better ways to solve this problem. What are you really trying to achieve? What kind of an app is this? Using `iframe` is going to be an uphill battle for you. I am speaking from experience here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using HTML5 Drag and Drop

```
<script id="dnd">
  function over(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.dataset.id);
  }

  function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(
      parent.document.querySelector("[data-id='" + data + "']")
    );
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    var mods = document.querySelector("modules");    
    var script = document.getElementById("dnd");   
    var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob(
        ["<!doctype html>" + script.outerHTML + mods.outerHTML]
        , {"type": "text/html"}
      )
    );
  }
</script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li data-id="1" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">To drop 1</li>
    <li data-id="2" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">To drop 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<modules ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="over(event)">
  <module>Element</module>
  <module>Element</module>
  <module>Element</module>
  <style>
    module, li {
      border:1px solid #000;
      display:block;
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:5px;
    }
  </style>
</modules>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zo2bx4f7/

Comment: This is the way I have done it. Took me a while to get the pros and cons but browser support is pretty good nowadays and I don't have to support the older ones anyway. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

The same issue appears with [Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable).
I found that its because of the length of the tag. It must not be longer than 4 chars total.
Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2a9t0o/1/):

```js
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable-1'), {});
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable-2'), {});
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable-3'), {});
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable-4'), {});
```

```css
foo,
modu, modul, modules {
    display: block;
}

foo > bar,
modu > module,
modul > module,
modules > module {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.4.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>

<foo id="sortable-1">
    <bar>foo 1</bar>
    <bar>foo 2</bar>
    <bar>foo 3</bar>
</foo>

<br/><br/>

<modu id="sortable-2">
    <module>modu 1</module>
    <module>modu 2</module>
    <module>modu 3</module>
</modu>

<br/><br/>

<modul id="sortable-3">
    <module>modul 1</module>
    <module>modul 2</module>
    <module>modul 3</module>
</modul>

<br/><br/>

<modules id="sortable-4">
    <module>modules 1</module>
    <module>modules 2</module>
    <module>modules 3</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Pretty good! The 4 letter limitation is strange though. Thanks for your input!